# HDD Motor Spinning

Tags: pic, brushless-dc-motor

I'm trying to run a hdd motor using the  following link. http://theamateurprogrammer.blogspot.hk/2014/02/revitalizing-old-hard-drive-motors.html

Instead of using Audrino I'm using PIC16F73.I tried to recreate the code in MPLAB but I couldn't convert `micros()` function. Therefore I am trying to create the waveform shown as in fig[image]

But I couldn't calculate the correct time period for switching. I have included my switching code.

```
PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;
   PORTBbits.RB1 = 0;
   PORTBbits.RB2 = 0;
   Delay_x100uS(45);

   PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;
   PORTBbits.RB1 = 1;
   PORTBbits.RB2 = 0;
   Delay_x100uS(15);


    PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;
   PORTBbits.RB1 = 1;
   PORTBbits.RB2 = 0;
     Delay_x100uS(45);

     PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;
   PORTBbits.RB1 = 1;
   PORTBbits.RB2 = 1;
   Delay_x100uS(15);


    PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;
   PORTBbits.RB1 = 0;
   PORTBbits.RB2 = 1;
    Delay_x100uS(45);

     PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;
   PORTBbits.RB1 = 0;
   PORTBbits.RB2 = 1;
   Delay_x100uS(15);
```

What should be the correct switching time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The base waveform can be divided into 6 points, each point with the same delay between them.  The length of that delay defines the speed of the motor.

[image]

The 6 points, or phases are:

1. Phase A HIGH
2. Phase C LOW
3. Phase B HIGH
4. Phase A LOW
5. Phase C HIGH
6. Phase B LOW

You notice the sequence of phases is repeated, but the signals inverted. Basically it's 3 square waves with a 120° phase shift.

Here's another way of looking at it - as a circle split into 6 segments, each segment defining a changed signal level (the signal changes at the interfaces to each segment):

[image]

As you work around the circle so the motor turns.

If I were then to create concentric rings for each of the three phases you can see better how then then turn on and off and interact with each other:

[image]

You can see from that how three coils A B and C located A at 3:00, B at 7:30 and C at 10:30 (90°, 210° and 330°) the interaction between them forms 6 distinct locations - when A is on the magnet is pulled to A, when B is on, it's pulled to B, but when both A and B are on it's pulled to half-way between them.

In reality a motor would often have multiples of 3 coils forming multiples of 6 points around the circle, increasing the torque, smoothness of rotation, etc.

So your code would actually be much simpler as far as the switching goes:

```
PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;  // Phase 1
Delay_x100uS(speed);
PORTBbuts.RB2 = 0;  // Phase 2
Delay_x100uS(speed);
PORTBbuts.RB1 = 1;  // Phase 3
Delay_x100uS(speed);
PORTBbits.RB0 = 0;  // Phase 4
Delay_x100uS(speed);
PORTBbuts.RB2 = 1;  // Phase 5
Delay_x100uS(speed);
PORTBbuts.RB1 = 0;  // Phase 6
Delay_x100uS(speed);
```

What value should "speed" be? As I said, that defines the speed of rotation of the motor.  I would suggest starting with a high value so the motor starts off slow, then gradually decreasing it, thus accelerating the motor to a higher speed.  Maybe tie the value to an analogue input and use a potentiometer to set the speed?

Comment: Thank u for your reply. I am using a 5400rpm motor. Should the speed be given as an rpm value and such that the potentiometer divides this rpm value.

Comment: You need to convert your target RPM into a delay-between-phase value. That would be dependant on the number of poles in the motor.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment i was able to rotate the motor and at variable speeds now.

Comment: @ Majenko - not Google
hey i wanna clarify a doubt when i try to spin the motor it takes more than 2 amps and because my dc supply doesnt support more than 2 amps it comes to a halt. now i m using battery. at first i used bd139 transistor to spin the motor but becoz it doesnt support current greater than 2 amps i used TIP122 darlington transistor dats when the problem started. Thanks in advance

Comment: @NikhilBenGeorge And what is the actual problem you are seeing then?

Comment: the motor is now jerking. it was working fine before replacing the transistors